# stop iphone site opening on PC

Tags: iphone, .htaccess

My iphone site is visible more on google search than original site. And it runs on PC as a iphone site, which is a bit distracting. I want to redirect to main site if it is not iphone device.

I tried this htaccess code but it's not working for me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^"iPhone" [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi guy, you should firstly handle your previous question. Accept an answer or do something else.

Comment: @sunekhappy.. Thank you for notifying me :) Now i did it!